# Does passing in key value pairs also protect against SQL injection attacks?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I came across this example where instead of using the bind parameters, a key value pair is passed in to the heredoc. I understand that this will allow the user to enter input in any order, but my question is, if I were to use key value pairs instead of bind parameters, would it still be protected against SQL injection attacks? If not, is there a way to allow users to pass input in without any specific ordering while also protecting against injection attacks?

Here is the example using key value pairs:

```
def self.find_by_id(id)
    found_user = QuestionDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, id: id)
      SELECT
        users.*
      FROM
        users
      WHERE
        users.id = :id
    SQL
    found_user.nil? ? nil : User.new(found_user)
  end
```

Here is the example using bind parameters:

```
def self.find_by_id(id)
    found_user = QuestionDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, id)
      SELECT
        users.*
      FROM
        users
      WHERE
        users.id = ?
    SQL
    found_user.nil? ? nil : User.new(found_user)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no syntax for passing parameters to a heredoc. What you're showing is really just passing a hash as the argument to `execute()`.

Ruby allows the argument to be a scalar or an array or hash.

```
require 'pp'

def execute(sql, binds)
        pp binds
end

id = 123

execute('blah blah blah', id: id)

execute('blah blah blah', id)
```

Output:

```
{:id=>123}
123
```

It's not actually combining the `id` with the string, it's just passing it as arguments to the `execute()` function. The first time, it's passing a hash, so you get the key-value pairs associated. The second time, it's just passing a scalar.

Presumably the real Rails `execute()` method has some code to check whether the argument passed was a scalar or a hash, and then it parses the named parameter placeholders out of the SQL string, and if the RDBMS you use doesn't support named parameters, it replaces them with `?` placeholders.

Either way, it's safe with respect to SQL injection.

Comment: Ah ok, so if I understand this correctly, passing in instance variables directly in the WHERE clause makes the code prone/vulnerable to SQL injection attacks because users could put in malicious code and there are no checks being done before that variable is used. But symbols and other bind variables are checked beforehand for malicious characters?

Comment: SQL injection works only if the malicious content can be inserted into the query when it's a string, before it is parsed by the RDBMS server. 
Bind variables are kept separate from the SQL query string, until _after_ the SQL syntax has been parsed by the RDBMS server. It's too late by then for any malicious content to change the logic of the query.